# xslt/saxon - using key() with collection() : content is not allowed in prolog?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a collection of tei-xml docs at `file:///Users/username/foopath`. I need to access these docs from an XSLT 2.0 transformation for a key.

I have a key that should search for matches in those docs at `//tei:seg[@type='dep_event']/@corresp`

So, I declare a variable for the collection of documents:

```
 <xsl:variable name="coll" 
    select="collection('file:///Users/username/foopath')"/>
```

And a key:

```
<xsl:key name="correspidkey" 
     match="tei:seg[@type='dep_event' and @corresp]" 
     use="@corresp"></xsl:key>
```

I then deploy the key against the collection as follows (which rejects any unwanted returns from `self::`) :

```
  <xsl:variable name="correspvar" 
     select="self::seg[@type='dep_event' and @corresp]/@corresp"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$coll/(key('correspidkey',$correspvar) 
            except $correspvar)/upper-case(@id)" 
            separator=", "/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
```

Saxon HE 9.6.07 returns `Content is not allowed in prolog`, but I can't identify what this error indicates exactly. If I remove this line, the error goes way and the file processes fine. Perhaps my use of `collection()` with the key?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you run Saxon from the command line? Or within any Java code? Do you have any collection resolver supposed to map your URI `file:///Users/username/foopath` to those docs? If you use plain Saxon from the command line or from Java the standard resolver use to e.g. load all "*.xml" files from the directory `file:///Users/username/foopath` would be `collection('file:///Users/username/foopath?select=*.xml')`.

Comment: See also http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/sourcedocs/collections.html

Comment: I am using Oxygen to write and test XSL and XML and it initially threw the error - adding `?select=*.xml` solved it. Now I understand that Saxon didn't like getting non-XML or rather, non-treatable files. It's too big a process for Oxygen so I've thrown it into command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because your call on `collection()` has selected files that are not well-formed XML. You can filter out non-XML files either (a) by using `;select=*.xml` in the collection URI, or (b) by using `;on-error=ignore`.